# Does Cloud Foundry only read/loads the index.html page?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Does Cloud Foundry only load up the index page? Is it possible to configure Cloud Foundry to load up another page? Ex: localhost:8080/products

Comment: What language are you using? What version of Cloud Foundry are you using?

Comment: java, with spring boot. I convert project into jar and push it up to pivotal web services @EngineerBetter

Comment: This is Spring Boot telling you that there's been an error, but you haven't configured an error page so it's showing you it's default one. This is not related to Cloud Foundry and path mapping.

Comment: @EngineerBetter Sorry sir, This is the updated image. hard coded data are populated, but not my auto populated ones

Comment: Your current issues have no relation to the question you've originally asked. Please mark one of the answer as correct, and raise a new question more specific to your app not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can put your index.html into a "products" directory and then when users request /products it will load the /products/index.html file.

If you want to have several applications with different paths you can create routes with path's.

```
cf create-route example.com -n host --path products
```

That will allow you to deploy multiple apps to the same host `host.example.com` but with different paths.

Otherwise you can configure a redirect in your application that redirects requests to `/` to `/products` but that would be wholly dependent upon the platform your application is using.

Comment: Thank you! So for some reason when I switched from index to products, My tables are not being populated. But when I run it from eclipse it will populate those tables. Am I doing something wrong with springboot?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry will serve all traffic that your app normally serves. If you app listens on many paths, then there is no reason that those should not also be accessible via Cloud Foundry. If Cloud Foundry deems your app to be healthy, then it is able to send HTTP requests to the app on the correct port, so anything beyond that must be app configuration.

I suspect that you have some sort of context mapping problem in your app.

Comment: would connecting to ssh2 in the app cause this error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: My application has a command to connect to (ganymend) ssh2 and retrieve a data then closes the connection. I was asking if cloud foundry is not compatiable to connect to an ssh2 server to retrieve data.

Comment: Should that stop it from serving other pages? Have you used `cf logs` to see what your app is doing?

Cloud Foundry has the notion of application security groups, that can be configured to restrict outbound traffic from application containers - if those aren't configured to allow outbound SSH traffic, then perhaps that could be a problem? I don't see why that would impact what paths your app responds to though.